# Regression(?): InternetGetConnectedState returns TRUE always under Windows 11

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-11, wininet

In my app I'm using `InternetGetConnectedState` to determine if the system is online.

I was using `Windows 10` and it was always working fine.

Recently I've upgraded my machine to `Windows 11` and found that it's not working anymore: it's returning `TRUE` always.

In its `lpdwFlags` parameter it returns 18, which means `LAN (0x2) | RasInstalled (0x10)`.

I think this is a regression and it's related to Ras (I connect using Dial-up).

Two questions:

1. Is it really a bug, or me misusing this function in some way?
2. Is there a known workaround for my config?

Comment: [According to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate) this is not recommended, have you tried calling `INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity` instead?

Comment: `InternetGetConnectedState()` has never been very reliable, you should not be using it at all.

Comment: You can [send feedback to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332) and `INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity` is reliable and easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [InternetGetConnectedState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate) recommends,

> use the INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity method instead.

There is a Microsoft sample [NetworkListManager](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/NetworkListManager/Utility.cpp#L62) which is uploaded recently.

[image]

[image]